# How to draw a table with dynamic data using D3 and DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, datatables

I am trying to draw a table using D3 and also using `DataTable()` for other functionalities like sorting the columns, overall table search etc. But I am not able to go along with DataTable. I have dynamic `data` coming which I will have to populate in the table dynamically(extra rows addition). For this, I delete the entire table everytime I am tabulating the table. I am able to do it with normal d3 table, but when I try to use the DataTable, it throws the below error.

I have a drop-down menu from which user can select any item. `listen_change` listens for such a change and draws the table with data corresponding to that item which I fetch using ajax from DB. DB keeps getting updated from somewhere else.

I want to know a way to use `DataTable` without reinitialising it (as the error alert tells) for my dynamic table. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I am getting the following alert,

> DataTables warning: table id=table_id - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/3

The Javascript part of the code is:

```
function listen_change() {
var timeOutId = 0;
document.getElementById('select_item').addEventListener('change',function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("select_item");
    var item_name = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    clearTimeout(timeOutId);
    (function worker() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/my_url/' + item_name + '/',
            success: function(data) {
                //delete_table(table_id)
                table_data(data)
            },
            complete: function() {
                // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
                timeOutId = setTimeout(worker, 3000);
            }
        });
    })();
});
}
function table_data(data){
    //puts data in the format required to draw D3 table
    tabulate(table_id, data, columns)
}

function tabulate(container, data, columns){
    var table = d3.select(container).attr("width",1)
    var thead = table.append('thead')
    var tbody= table.append('tbody')
    var headers = thead.append("tr")
                       .selectAll("th")
                       .data(columns)
                       .enter()
                       .append("th")
                       .text(function(column) {
                                return column; 
                            })
    // create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("tr");
    // create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(row) {
                            return columns.map(function(column,id) {
                                                return {column: column, value: row[column]};
                                                }); 
                    })  
                    .enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .attr("style", "font-family: Arial") // sets the font style
                    .html(function(d) { 
                            return d.value; 
                        });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var o_table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
                                    'bSort': true,
                                    'bFilter': true,
                                    "autoWidth":true,
                                    "scrollY":        "600px",
                                    "scrollCollapse": true,
                                    "info":           true,
                                    "paging":        true,
                                    "bLengthChange" : true,
                                    "iDisplayLength":60,
                                    "aLengthMenu" : [30,60,100],
                                    });
                    })
    return table;
}
```

The html part is:

```
<div>
    <table class="table table--bordered table--highlight" align='center' cellspacing=50 cellpadding=20 id="table_id">
    </table>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        listen_change();
     });
    </script>
```

**UPDATE 1**

I tried giving `'bDestroy' : true` in `DataTable()`and I am clearing data inside the table using `$('table_id').empty()`. This helps me in destroying the `DataTable` instance and helps me replace the table and thus the data changes dynamically. But, this brings me to a new problem now. I am updating the table every 3 seconds as mentioned in the code. Now, if user tries to search for anything using the search option, it works but after 3 seconds, the whole table comes up back. How to update the data dymanaically without affecting the search feature? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.